# How To Switch Repo Type in VSO

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

We are currently using TFVC for our repository in Visual Studio Online and I was wondering if there was an easy way to switch Repo Types (we are changing it to git)? I understand you can create a new project, but that means we would have to move all of our backlog items over to the new project. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Your only recourse at the moment is to create a new team project and migrate to it.

Comment: Is there an easy way to migrate the items in the backlog?